# group by first letter of the string

Tags: c#, sql, group-by

I have a Person table, with huge number of records, and want to group by duplicate persons in it,
by one of requirements persons are duplicates, if they have the same family name, and the first letter of first names are equal, so I want to group by first name, and first letter of family name, is there a way to group in sql like this? I need this in C#, so some code processing could be done, but the number of persons is huge, so it should be fast algorithm.

Comment: To get "fast" solution you need to add one more column `char(1)` and maintain it with triggers.

Comment: @zerkms, I dont think triggers is the way to go if you wish to achieve this. You can also use Computed Columns. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx

Comment: @astander: not a big difference, but indeed, may be handy. Is everything ok with indexing computed columns?

Comment: Yes, I do belive the link states that indexes can be created on such columns. Just as an after thought, if an Index was created on say (Surname, FirstName), the index will perform well when using LEFT or LIKE 'xx%' as the values will be indexed from left to right. Issues start to occur when you wish to use RIGHT or '%xx'.

Comment: @astander: what if computed column returns some random value, or, for example, current time? Will not the values in index be obsolete right after indexing? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MEMBER.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, COUNT(MEMBER.MEMBER_LASTNAME)
FROM dbo.MEMBER
GROUP BY MEMBER.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, SUBSTRING(MEMBER.MEMBER_LASTNAME, 1,1)
HAVING COUNT(MEMBER.MEMBER_LASTNAME) > 1
```

This query will give you all (members in this case) where the first name is the same and the last name's first letter is the same for more than one member. In other words duplicates as you've defined it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, from SqlServer you can do something like

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        Surname,
        LEFT(FirstName,1) FirstNameLetter
FROM    Persons
```

Other than that, we will need a little bit more detail. Table schema, expected result set, etc...

Comment: @astander this doesn't give the expected desired result. For one, he wants to group by firstname and first letter of lastname. You've got that backwards. And secondly, this will be non-deterministic (if it works) besides won't show the duplicates - which is what the OP is looking for (indirectly).

Comment: from the OP question *requirements persons are duplicates, if they have the same family name, and the first letter of first names are equal* and where Im from family name is Surname, yes?

Comment: @astander, yes you're correct. Later in the question I believe he states it backwards

Comment: Yea @astander you are correct, but I need duplicate records with first name, family name for user to analyze and decide if there are the same, and don't want to distinct

Comment: @arsenMkrt, the SQL I posted in my answer does that. You get only the duplicates as per your definition.